# How do I add and delete array strings using jQuery in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm trying to add and delete array strings using jQuery in Typescript.

The program adds a person which includes a delete button but it doesn't display both surname and othername input values, only one and the first time I press the Insert button, it doesn't display any values until I press the button again.

How do I allow the user to enter in input values then display both surname and othername when I press the "Insert" button?

How do I also implement a simple prompt message when deleting a person?

Error messages when compiling with tsc:

```
Person.ts: error TS2339: Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

Desired output example:

```
Person 1 (values entered above, first press of button)
Surname: Smith (del-btn)
Othername: Matt (del-btn)

Person 2: (values in inputs reset, new values entered)
Surname: Williams (del-btn)
Othername: Robert (del-btn)
```

I'm using jQuery but I would be more than happy to receive a Typescript alternative.

Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/Person.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form id="form1" name="form1">
            <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" /><br />
            <label for="othername">Other Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="othername" id="othername" /><br />
                <input onclick="newFunction()" id="Button-insert" type="button" value="Insert" />
            <p id="demo"></p>
                <input type="button" id="Button-reset" value="Reset">                   
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Typescript/ jQuery:

```
function newFunction() {

    var all_values =[], demo = $("#demo"), form = $("#form1")[0], surname = $("#surname"), othername = $("#othername");

    $('#Button-insert').click(function(){
    var temp_val = surname.val();
    var temp_va12 = othername.val();
    all_values.push(temp_val);
    all_values.push(temp_val2);

    // create delete button along with the value
    demo.append(
    '<p>'+temp_val+' <button value="'+temp_val+'" type="button" class="del-btn">Delete</button></p>',
    '<p>'+temp_val2+' <button value="'+temp_val2+'" type="button" class="del-btn">Delete</button></p>',
    );
    form1.reset();
    });

    $('#Button-reset').click(function(){
    all_values = []; 
    demo.html('');
    });

    demo.on('click', '.del-btn', function(){
    all_values.splice(all_values.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    });

}
```

Comment: To avoid any clash with the `new` operator, you should rename your function.

Comment: You haven't really identified exactly what your specific  problem is or where you are having troubles. Take a few minutes to read [ask] then [edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43591387/edit) with specifics like what works and what doesn't and what it needs to do differently

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, I've clarified and improved the question!

Comment: [Check this](http://thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/post.cfm/jquery-tip-finding-adding-and-removing-values-from-arrays) Hope this helpful.